# Typedoc does not generate documentation for imported modules

Tags: node.js, typescript, import, documentation, typedoc

I'm getting an empty documentation when to generating with TypeDoc.

This is only for imported files. When I add any class to the file specified in `entryPoints`, I get documentation for that, but for imported files I get nothing.

I have such typedoc.json:

```json
{
  "entryPoints": ["src/app.ts"],
  "out": "docs",
  "includes": "src"
}
```

The entrypoint file imports all other files and modules, but TypeDoc generates nothing for those imported modules.

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 0):

I should use `--entryPointStrategy expand` instead.

Comment: Also set it to "Expand"

Comment: I tried all different values, didn't make any difference to me.