# Why TypeDoc don't process local file imports?

Tags: typescript, typedoc

I tried [this answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69259376/typedoc-does-not-generate-doc-for-imported-modules)
TypeDoc doesn't generate documentation for local files.
I used the command: `yarn typedoc` and I have the tsconfig.json, here is a part of this

```
"typedocOptions": {
      "entryPoints": ["src/main.ts"],
      "out": "docs"
  }
```

--entryPointStrategy doesn't work in any value.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

In my case the solution was run typedoc with this command

```
npx typedoc --entryPointStrategy expand ./src
```

Inside `./src` there is a file `index.tsx` - it`s entry point of my app

More

1. [docs](https://typedoc.org/guides/options/#entrypointstrategy)
2. [typedoc issue](https://github.com/TypeStrong/typedoc/issues/1871)

You may also need these plugins

1. [typedoc-plugin-missing-exports](https://www.npmjs.com/package/typedoc-plugin-missing-exports)
2. [typedoc-plugin-not-exported](https://www.npmjs.com/package/typedoc-plugin-not-exported)